# Typescript: Using Objects as Properties - how is the correct way of doing that:

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have declared a property as a custom class, and I'm trying to access its methods after I instanciate the object of the main class. But I'm getting the following error when I try to access my property methods:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fcm' of undefined
```

This is how I have declared my class and property:

```
class PushController {
  
  public fcm: FCMServerSide = new FCMServerSide('myKey')
  
    async getInstanceTokenInfo(request: Request, response: Response) {
    try {
        const {
            token
        } = request.body

        console.log("==> Token Info: ", token)

        const apidata = await this.fcm.getInstanceTokenInfo(String(token))

        if (token) {
            return response.json({result: true, apidata })
        } else {
            return response.json({result: false, message:"No Token Provided"})
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return response.json({ result: false, message: e.stack })
    }

}
```

Apparently I'm getting the error when I call this.fcm.getInstanceTokenInfo method.

Checking my code, I can see that I am correctly generating an instance in my routing script:

```
...
import PushController from './controllers/PushController'

const routes = express.Router();

const pushController = new PushController()

routes.post('/push-token/instance/info', pushController.getInstanceTokenInfo)
```

As you see above, I'm using express to generate the routes. What can I do to corret this error?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a constructor to instantiate the PushController class.
Something like this:

```
class PushController {

public fcm: FCMServerSide;
constructor(){
    this.fcm = new FCMServerSide('myKey')
}

  async getInstanceTokenInfo(request: Request, response: Response) {
  try {
      const {
          token
      } = request.body

      console.log("==> Token Info: ", token)

      const apidata = await this.fcm.getInstanceTokenInfo(String(token))

      if (token) {
          return response.json({result: true, apidata })
      } else {
          return response.json({result: false, message:"No Token Provided"})
      }
  } catch (e) {
      return response.json({ result: false, message: e.stack })
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but I have already tried this way as well, and I'm getting the same results...

Comment: You are welcome, when I have more time, I'll try to simulate your project and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
When we pass a class method for the router we loose the "this" instance.
So you can use this way to solve your problem:

```
 import PushController from './controllers/PushController'
    const routes = express.Router();
    const pushController = new PushController()
    routes.post('/push-token/instance/info', pushController.getInstanceTokenInfo.bind(pushController))
```